# Coldfusion ORM/Hibernate StaleStateException

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion

I'm getting the following errors every time I perform very simple save operations on Coldfusion 9.01 ORM:

Exception in Hibernate operation.
Either the updated/deleted row does not exist or the session contained stale data. Root cause :org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

The following code will actually update the object in the database, but this error appears at the bottom of the page, presumably when Coldfusion automatically calls ormFlush() at the end of the request.

```
<cfscript>
myDeal = entityloadbypk('serviceCategory',1);
myDeal.setScName('Automotive1');
EntitySave(myDeal);
writedump(myDeal);
</cfscript>
```

Here is the object I'm working with, however this same problem occurs when doing this with multiple objects.

```
<cfscript>
/** 
* @persistent 
* @table y_serviceCategories
*/ 
component{ 
    property name="scID" fieldtype="id" datatype="int" generator="native"; 
    property string scName; 
    property priority; 

    property name="serviceSubCategory" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="serviceSubCategory" fkcolumn="scID";

    public array function getSubCategoryByPriority(){
        return EntityLoad("serviceSubCategory", {scID=getscID()}, "Priority ASC");
    }
}
</cfscript>
```

My current thought is that there is some stale object (unrelated to the object in the code) in the Hibernate batch that fails every time Hibernate runs an add/update batch.  Please help!!!

Comment: Have you turned on this.ormsettings.logsql in Application.cfc?

Comment: yes, i turned this on.  I'm confused where to find the output though.  Is it supposed to be in one of the standard Coldfusion logs?

Comment: yes, out log of your app

Comment: individual apps have a log?  Where are they located?

Comment: #appname#-out.log, depends on your installation.

Comment: Henry is not correct. Here's a blog post from a ColdFusion engineer that explains how to enable sql logging and how to specify where the log data will go: http://www.rupeshk.org/blog/index.php/2009/07/coldfusion-orm-how-to-log-sql/

Comment: Can you update your question to include the ORMSettings configuration section of your Application.cfc?

Comment: I'm not correct? hmm... but that's where my SQL logging goes...

Comment: if you suspect "Coldfusion automatically calls ormFlush() at the end of the request", why don't u disable it and try?

Comment: Henry, unless you've done additional configuration, the default place for the sql logging to go is into `{instance-name}-out.log`, mixed in with all of the other instance console logging.

Comment: @DannyLeavitt are you storing any orm entities in persistent scopes (session, application, server)?

Comment: I've had StaleStateExceptions too but it was never the code. The problem disappeared after a `ORMReload()`, `applicationStop()`. But I assume your tried this already. Is the database table generated by ORM or by you?

Answer (score 0):

For kicks, try adding

```
ORMFLush();
```

after

```
EntitySave(myDeal);
```